# UISwipeGestureRecognizer is not working?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uigesturerecognizer

I am using following code to rotate the view when swipeEvent is happened in iPad (using UISwipeGestureRecognizer).But when I continuously does Swipping(2 or 3), the Method is not called, I know the reason , I have used Duration in that method for CABasicAnimation.How can i overvome this problem? anyHelp please?

```
-(void)handleSwipeFromD:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
 NSLog(@"down");
if (operationStart)
{

self.commonLayer = [self.layer presentationLayer];
self.layer.transform = commonLayer.transform;
[self.commonLayer removeAnimationForKey:@"rotationAnimate"];

self.commonLayer = self.layer;
rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
rotationAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0 * M_PI];
rotationAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:2.0 * M_PI];
//rotationAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 2.5 * 3.15 ];
rotationAnimation.duration = 1.0;
rotationAnimation.cumulative = YES;
rotationAnimation.repeatCount = 1.0; 
//rotationAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];
[self.commonLayer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"rotationAnimate"];

  }  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The following, placed in the view's controller and not in the view, works like a charm many many times.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *sw = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFromD:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:sw];
    [sw release];
}


-(void)handleSwipeFromD:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    BOOL operationStart = YES;
    if (operationStart)
    {
        //self.view.la
    //  self.view.commonLayer = [self.layer presentationLayer];
    //  self.view.layer.transform = commonLayer.transform;
        [self.view.layer removeAnimationForKey:@"rotationAnimate"];

        CABasicAnimation *rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
        rotationAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0 * M_PI];
        rotationAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:2.0 * M_PI];
        //rotationAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 2.5 * 3.15 ];
        rotationAnimation.duration = 1.0;
        rotationAnimation.cumulative = YES;
        rotationAnimation.repeatCount = 1.0; 
        //rotationAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];
        [self.view.layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"rotationAnimate"];

    }  
}
```

It is not, however, the same layer hierarchy you have since I removed all "commonLayer" references and I don't really get from your code what role it plays.

Comment: hi , you are right, but rotation is not happening from the last stage of angle(transform),when we swipe again, it goes to begining stage and then rotation is happening